# Button is not getting displayed in Relative layout

Tags: android, button, android-relativelayout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/main_screen_image"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/facebook_login_button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/button1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/have_a_look_text_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can any body please tell me why button2 is not getting displayed, I am really not able to figure it out

Comment: @Oil , I did but its not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Because button1 is aligned to the parent's bottom

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

and button2 is requested to be below button1

```
android:layout_below="@id/button1"
```

so button2 is not visible

Comment: Ohhh That did the trick but I want button1 to be at just above bottom layer , So am I using correct layout or should I use relative layout ? My apology if am not pretty clear

Comment: I would place both buttons into a vertical LinearLayout and align that LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout as needed. On the other hand I'm not sure if I understand how you want the buttons.

Comment: Let me try Alex . Thank you so much for the help. Meanwhile I am not good with layout design, can  you please tell me any good website or resource where I can learn about GUI design ?

Comment: you can take a look right here about layout design, there are a some good lessons to try:http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/202-lesson-4-layout-elements-and-their-properties.html http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/203-lesson-5-layout-file-fo-ractivity-xml-representation-changing-screen-orientation.html http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/207-lesson-6-layout-types-key-differences-and-properties.html http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/208-lesson-7-layout-parameters-for-view-elements.html